# expected string or buffer in python

Tags: python

I have this:

```
fin = open(blah)
fin_lower= fin.readlines()
lines = [fin_lower.lower() for line in fin]
lines = line.split()
```

It gives:

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Is it wrong to readlines?

Answer (score 1):

[readlines](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) returns a list containing all lines of data, it looks like you have a bug, and you probably want to do this:

```
lines = [line.lower() for line in fin_lower]
```

Your code is also mixing variables around, take a good step through it, what are you trying to accomplish? You seem to mix `line` and `lines` a bunch.

Comment: Right, you have a problem there, what exactly are you trying to do with that statement?

Answer (score 1):

`re.sub` expects a string as the third argument, you gave it `lines` which is a list. Also, you're iterating over `fin` after consuming all lines of it with `readlines`. You seem to be trying to do:

```
with open(blah) as fin:
    lines = [line.lower().replace(',', '').split() for line in fin]
```

Also note that you don't need `re` to do a literal replacement.

Comment: @NantiaDiko Yep, I added a call of `lower()`. Forgot it at first.

Comment: @NantiaDiko Because `lines` is now a list of lists because of `split()`. You can try printing things to understand what's going on in your script.

Comment: @NantiaDiko Indeed, strings don't have a `remove` method, lists do. How can I help?

Comment: @NantiaDiko Don't get me wrong, but this is becoming a little unconstructive. I suggest that you: 1) read a tutorial about Python's standard data types; 2) play with them in an interactive Python interpreter of your choice. You'll see how `split` and `startswith` work with strings and how `remove` and `for` loops work with lists.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Bartek

I was able to get this done.

```
import os
import signal
import time
import sys
import re
import string

fin = open('blah','r')
fin_lower= fin.readlines()

lines=""

for line in fin_lower:
lines += line.lower()


line = re.sub(';',' ',lines)
lines = line.split()
print lines
```

Initial Contents of File blah

VISHAL;
KHIALANI;
NONOE;
CANGETITDONE;

Final Output

['vishal', 'khialani', 'nonoe', 'cangetitdone']