# 'TypeError: expected string or buffer' when performing re.sub on beautiful soup result set iteration

Tags: regex, python-2.7, iteration, beautifulsoup, substitution

content_a is a beautiful soup result set (ie the type is `<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>`) that is made up of values whose type is `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`.

If i print 'content_a' i get:

```
[<div class="class1 class2">Here is the first sentence.
 <br/> <br/> Here is some text "and some more text."
 <br/> <br/> Here is another sentence.
 <br/> Text<br/><span class="class3">Text</span></div>, <div class="class1 class2">Here is the first sentence.
 <br/> <br/> Here is some text "and some more text."
 <br/> <br/> Here is another sentence.
 <br/> Text<br/><span class="class3">Text</span></div>, etc
```

So it seems to me it should be a simple iterable list of divs.

I am wanting to replace `<div class="class1 class2">` with `<div class="class1 class2"><p>` (my eventual goal being to replace all `<br />`'s with paragraph tags).

In my test where the source content is a string I have:

```
import re
blablabla = ['<div class="class1 class2">', '<div class="class1 class2">']
for _ in blablabla:
    _ = re.sub('(<div class=\"class1 class2\">)', r"\1<p>",_)
    print _
```

which returns, as required:

```
<div class="class1 class2"><p>
<div class="class1 class2"><p>
```

I am trying to perform the same process on each iterable in content_a with:

```
import re
for _ in content_a:
    _ = re.sub('(<div class=\"class1 class2\">)', r"\1<p>",_)
    print _
```

but am getting the error:

```
...in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

So the only difference that i can tell between the two examples is that one is a beautiful soup result set and one is just a plain list.

Can anyone see why this error could be occuring?

**Edit:**

Someone has pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14083072/1063287) that sub requires a string as the third argument, so the third argument that i am passing is the iterable value which is of type `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`.  So perhaps this is the problem.  But i need to retain the nature of these values for later modification so i am not sure how to proceed at the moment.

**Update/Workaround:**

Just to save someone spending time on an answer, i figured out a workaround, basically i realised i could adjust the content later in the process and i did this by converting it to a string with `read()` and could then perform all the re.sub changes on the required elements in the string.

And the little regex i came up with was:

`string = re.sub('([^\r]*)\r', r'\1</p>\n<p>', string)`

Comment: Since you found the answer, you can post that answer as an actual answer for your question, then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, I am posting the workaround I used as the solution:

**Update/Workaround:**

Just to save someone spending time on an answer, I figured out a workaround, basically I realised I could adjust the content later in the process and i did this by converting it to a string with `read()` and could then perform all the re.sub changes on the required elements in the string.

And the little regex I came up with was:

`string = re.sub('([^\r]*)\r', r'\1</p>\n<p>', string)`